# Is it possible to add a ActionEvent Handler to a javaFX Textfield using addEventHandler method?

Tags: event-handling, textfield, javafx-2

I tried to add action handlers to text field using the addEventHandler() but seem not to be working. Is it even possible o is it a bug? If I try the same with Button control everything is fine.

Here is the sample code:

```
package com.teste;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class EventHandlerTest extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    stage.setTitle("Custom JavaFX Event");
    TextField btn = new TextField();
    btn.setId("Fire Button");
    btn.setText("Fire MyEvent'");

    btn.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            if (event.getEventType().equals(ActionEvent.ACTION)) {
                System.out.println("ActionEvent 2");
            }
        }     
    }); 

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    stage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Documentation says it should be possible, but can't find anything else. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

If you use [setOnAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html#setOnAction%28javafx.event.EventHandler%29) rather than [addEventHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#addEventHandler%28javafx.event.EventType,%20javafx.event.EventHandler%29), then you will be able to capture the ActionEvent for the TextField.

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("ActionEvent: " + event);
    }     
});
```

I don't know why the addEventHandler code does not capture the event.  I also tried addEventFilter as well and that did not work for me either (JavaFX 2.2).

Note that a TextField will generate an ActionEvent when you press the Enter key on the TextField.

Comment: Exactly, the only way to make it work now is using Convenience Method setOnAction AFAIK. So it is not possible to use addEventHandler?

Answer (score 0):

In java 8 now is possible

```
btn.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("ActionEvent: " + event);
        }
    });

//Lambda Notation
btn.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> {
        System.out.println("ActionEvent: " + event);
    });
```